# CButton gets send WM_SETSTYLE to BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON Message when clicked

Tags: mfc, focus

I have several `CButton` objects. When I click them, they get send a `WM_SETSTYLE` message changing the style from `BS_PUSHBUTTON` to `BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON`. This change is permanent and does not go away when I push another button.

```
CButton* button = new CButton;
button->Create(L"button", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE , CRect( 10,10,100,100), this, IDC_BUTTON);
```

What could cause that behaviour?

For testing purposes I created a new project from scratch. There the buttons don't get changed. But I am not able to figure out, what I do differently.

Comment: Potentially related: [The dangers of playing focus games when handling a WM_KILLFOCUS message](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/08/08/448969.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a Dialog or a window with child windows this states are handled by [WM_NEXTDLGCTL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/ms645432(v=vs.85).aspx) respective 
[CWnd::GotoDlgCtrl](http://CDialog::GotoDlgCtrl) and [CWNd::NextDlgCtrl/PrevDlgCtrl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/zbf9wz2k.aspx)

You should never use SetFocus in a Dialog when Buttons are involved.

Comment: That is a plausible explanation since I am actually using `SetFocus`. But that immediatly brings up a new question: How do I achieve the intended result without the use of `SetFocus`? Namely I want to have a custom drop down menu, that dissapears, when the users clicks somewhere else. I implemented that by setting the focus to that window and waiting for the `KillFocus` message. How does the `CComboBox` or the context menu implement that behaviour? Do you happen to have a pointer to that information?

Comment: Don't set the focus to the specific child. Set the focus to the parent (dialog). The parent dialog will set the focus back to the control that had the focus before. Than the dialog will do the rest... AFAIK a combo box uses a different approach. But wait: If the user clicks somewhere else, the focus is already moved, why are you trying to set the focus again WHEN you get WM_KILLFOCUS, that is wrong...

Comment: @sietschie: The ComboBox control calls [SetCapture](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646262.aspx) and responds to the [WM_CAPTURECHANGED](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645605.aspx) message.

Comment: @llinspectable: Ah yes. I remember, thanks for this valuable comment.